# Advice on token generation for links

Tags: python, django, token

Quite similar to the process of requesting a new password with the django auth views, when a user registers on my site they fill in a form which creates a user with the `is_active` flag set to `False`.

Then an email is sent to the site administrator to approve the registration. The email contains two buttons: 'accept' and 'reject'. When the administrator presses the 'accept' button it flips the `is_active` flag to `True` and sends an email to the user to notify them that their request has been approved. At the moment, if the administrator presses 'reject' all that happens is an email is sent to the user.

My issue is that when the accept button has been pressed, the token that is generated by `'token':token_generator.make_token(user)` is still valid after the link has been used. This is because the token is generated by 1. user pk,  2. user password hash, 3. last login date and 4. the current `datetime`. Therefore the difference between the before state of the user (`is_active=False`) and the after state of the user (`is_active=True`) are indistinguishable to the token generator. I want to avoid the possibility of the site admin pressing the accept button more than once and thereby sending out multiple acceptance emails.

I could solve this issue by;

a) creating a custom token generator class that inherits from the default token generator class and override `_make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp)` to include `is_active` in the hash or

b) update the `last_login` on the user when the link is pressed.

a) Feels like a more proper way of doing it, but it doesn't really help with invalidating the token when the reject button is pressed.

On the other hand, b) feels more hacky, but could be applied to both accept and reject options. I could potentially change the user model to have a flag that says that a user has been rejected and then use this in conjunction with the a) method. I can see the usefulness of having some explicit database change showing when the user has been rejected, but at the same time I feel quite reluctant to change the user model.

What would be the best course to take? Or if there's some better solution then please let me know!

Comment: If the token has the time that it was generated, you could not accept the token if `last_login` has changed after the token timestamp? I wouldn't try to change the `last_login` value, leave that as the actual time (handled by django) that the account was logged into.

Comment: The `last_login` is null when the token is created and remains null until the user logs in to their activated account, which is not possible if the admin has rejected their request. So the token can't be invalidated when the admin chooses to reject.